# NotesHTTPRequest Put method response code

Tags: lotusscript, hcl-notes

I am trying to call a put request using NotesHTTPRequest (HCL Notes Release 11.0.1 SHF92)
Unfortunately, it seems the returned response code is wrong.

When I call the service using Postman with a valid body, I get response code 204 No Content. This is intended, since the service is not returning any response.
If - using Postman - I use a wrong body, I get response code 500 with an error message.

I am trying the same in a lotusscript agent

```
Dim request As NotesHTTPRequest
Set request = session.Createhttprequest()
Dim jsnav as NotesJsonNavigator

'... build jsnav ...'

Call request.Setheaderfield("Authorization", "Basic " + EncodeBase64 (user + ":" + password))
request.preferstrings = True
Dim response As String
response = request.put(url, jsnav.stringify())
    
Print request.Responsecode
```

The code prints 'HTTP/1.1 100 Continue', regardless the content in jsnav.

Is ResponseCode not implemented for a put request?

Is there a way to get the same response code as it is returned using Postman?

Unfortunately I cannot give any details on the called api, since this is a private company service.

Update:
It seems that there is more going on, because - when I put the request with wrong authentication credentials, I still get 100 (in Notes, not in Postman).

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you are running into JCORBXUP3G which was fixed in 11.0.1 FP3 https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=kb_article&sys_id=54ab87b1db88f010cc426275ca96190e

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask the customer to upgrade (they have no fixpacks at all at the moment)